# compare la fecha actual con los dias jueves

Tags: javascript, html

estamos haciendo una pagina donde, por nuestra cuenta hicimos un login, pero dentro de la pagina quiere que con un js se compare la fecha actual con los dias jueves, para cuando sea jueves nos salte una ventana emergente que nos ponga que mañana es jueves y que se tiene que realizar X pago el viernes, pero ninguno de mi grupo sabemos como hacerlo y no tengo idea yo de donde guiarme para saber hacer esto

Comment: Deberias mostrar lo que has intentado como señalas las guías [ask], [answer] y pasar el [tour] para que conozcas como se trabaja en SO.

Answer (score 2):

aquí te dejo el código que buscas he comentado las partes que te podrían interesar.

```html
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['btnenviar'])){
    /* aqui el codigo del login */
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
 /* en realidad esto no es necesario - pero muestra la fecha  */
    var meses = new Array ("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
    var diasSemana = new Array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado");
    var f=new Date();
    document.write(diasSemana[f.getDay()] + ", " + f.getDate() + " de " + meses[f.getMonth()] + " de " + f.getFullYear());

function verificar(){
    /* declaramos una variable con la fecha actua*/
    var f = new Date();
    /* preguntamos si el dias es  3 osea miercoles */ 
    /* donde 0 = domingo y 6 = sabado */
    if(f.getDay() == 3){
         alert("Mañana es Jueves , Debes pagar 150 € el viernes")
    }
}


</script>


    <form method="post">
            <input type="text" id="txtusuario" name="txtusuario">
            <br>
            <input type="password" id="txtpassword" name="txtpassword">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" id="btnenviar" name="btnenviar" onclick="verificar()"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero ayúdanos a responder preguntas que sean creadas en base a lo definido en el [help], específicamente [ask], de esta forma la información será de ayuda para toda la comunidad y no únicamente para el que usuario que pregunta , saludos.